# Newton Raphson with continuation error

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I have here an algorithm to solve multivariable nonlinear systems using the Newton-Raphson method with continuation. However, there is some error in the code that I am unable to identify, causing it to go into infinite compilation, and the Kernel is unable to handle it, thus not generating a solution. Could someone assist me with this issue?

```
(* Define the system of equations F[x] == 0 *)
F[x_List] := {
  x[[1]]^2 + x[[2]]^2 - 1,
  x[[1]] + x[[2]] - 2
}

(* Define the initial variable vector *)
x0 = {0.5, 1.5}; (* Initial values of x and y *)

(* Define the maximum number of iterations and the tolerance *)
maxIter = 100; (* Maximum number of iterations *)
tolerance = 1.0e-6; (* Convergence tolerance *)

(* Define the initial continuation parameter (usually starts at 0) *)
mu = 0.0;

(* Main loop of the Newton-Raphson method with continuation *)
While[mu <= 1.0,
  x = x0; (* Initial value of variables *)
  iteration = 0;

  While[iteration < maxIter,
    (* Calculate the Jacobian matrix J *)
    J = D[F[x], {x}];

    (* Calculate the vector -F(x) *)
    negF = -F[x];

    (* Solve the linear system: J.dx = -F(x) *)
    dx = LinearSolve[J, negF];

    (* Update the variables: x = x + mu*dx *)
    x = x + mu * dx;

    (* Check for convergence *)
    If[Norm[dx] < tolerance,
      Break[];
    ];

    iteration++;
  ];

  (* Check if convergence is achieved *)
  If[iteration < maxIter,
    Print["Convergence achieved for mu =", mu];
    Print["Solution:", x];
    Break[];
  ];

  mu += 0.1; (* Increase the continuation parameter *)
]

If[mu > 1.0,
  Print["Convergence could not be achieved."];
]
```

Comment: Beware, the determinant is not a good way to check for singularity in general. It's better off to use `LinearSolve[]` itself to warn about singularity, and use things like `Check[]` to catch those cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some changes, your code works fine:

```
(*Define the system of equations F[x]*)

F[x1_, x2_] := {x1^2 + x2^2 - 2, 2 x1 + x2 - 1}

(*Define the initial variable vector*)
x = {0.8, 1.2}; (*Initial values of x1 and x2*)

(*Define the maximum number of iterations and the tolerance*)
maxIter = 100; (*Maximum number of iterations*)
tolerance = 1*10^-6; (*Convergence tolerance*)

iteration = 0;

While[iteration < maxIter,
 (*Calculate the Jacobian matrix J*)
 J = D[F[x1, x2], {{x1, x2}}] /. {x1 -> x[[1]], x2 -> x[[2]]};
 (*Check if the Jacobian is singular*)
 If[Det[J] == 0, Print["Singular Jacobian encountered."];
  Break[];];
 (*Calculate the vector-F(x)*)
 negF = -F[x[[1]], x[[2]]];
 (*Solve the linear system:J.dx=-F(x)*)
 dx = LinearSolve[J, negF];
 (*Update the variables:x=x+dx*)
 x = x + dx;
 (*Check for convergence*)
 If[Norm[F[x[[1]], x[[2]]]] < tolerance, Break[];];
 iteration++;]

(*Check if convergence is achieved*)
If[iteration < maxIter, 
 Print["Convergence achieved after ", iteration, " iterations."];
 Print["Solution:", x];, Print["Convergence could not be achieved."];]
```

The result:

[image]

You can compare the solution with `NSolveValues`:

```
NSolveValues[F[x1, x2] == 0, {x1, x2}, Reals]

(*{{-0.2, 1.4}, {1., -1.}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!

Comment: @LarissaSantos You're welcome, Larissa, I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

You can write a very short program using Mathematica functions:

```
f[x_, y_] = {x^2 + y^2 - 2, 2 x + y - 1};
jf[x_, y_] = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}];
FixedPointList[(# - LinearSolve[jf @@ #, f @@ #]) &, {0.8, 1.2}, 10]
```

{{0.8, 1.2}, {-0.525, 2.05}, {-0.257095, 1.51419}, {-0.20248,
1.40496}, {-0.200005, 1.40001}, {-0.2, 1.4}, {-0.2, 1.4}, {-0.2,
1.4}}